# Toolbar chevron doesn't expand when QPushbuttons added

Tags: python, qt, pyside, toolbar

I'm attempting to add a set of push buttons to a toolbar that can be toggled. When there are more buttons than can be displayed, the chevron appears, but it is greyed out and doesn't show the remaining contents.

Initially I had:

```
toolbar = QtGui.QToolbar()
newButton = QtGui.QPushButton('name')
newButton.toggled.connect(myAction)
toolbar.addWidget(newButton)
```

I read that I need to create a `customWidgetAction`, so I have tried the following:

```
toolbar = QtGui.QToolbar()
newButton = QtGui.QPushButton()
widgetAction = QtGui.QWidgetAction(newButton)
widgetAction.toggled.connect(myAction)
newWidget = widgetAction.createWidget(newButton)
toolbar.addWidget(newButton)
```

However using this code, the button doesn't appear in the toolbar. Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I see the same behavior. If widgets are added to a toolbar and the toolbar cannot display them all, it will display a chevron but the chevron will be greyed out. The chevron will not be greyed out for actions though and they will be displayed in a drop down fashion.

My example just using standard `QAction`s:

```
from PySide import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

tb = QtGui.QToolBar()

#tb.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton('AAA'))
#tb.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton('BBB'))
#tb.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton('CCC')) # will not be shown in case the toolbar is too short, chevron will be greyed

tb.addAction(QtGui.QAction('AAA', tb))
tb.addAction(QtGui.QAction('BBB', tb))
tb.addAction(QtGui.QAction('CCC', tb))
tb.addAction(QtGui.QAction('DDD', tb))
tb.addAction(QtGui.QAction('EEE', tb))

tb.resize(50, 40)
tb.show()

app.exec_()
```

and if you want to connect the action to something useful the pattern is:

```
toolbar = QtGui.QToolBar()
action = QtGui.QAction(icon, 'Create new scenario', toolbar)
action.triggered.connect(..)
toolbar.addAction(action)
```

`QWidgetAction` seems to be slightly more complex than just `QAction` although it should work as well. If you do not need the added functionality, rather use `QAction` and a simple icon.